# ChartEngine android, moving a chart from left to right every sec

Tags: android, charts

I would like to move a chart from left to right every second with Android:

if the first value would be the coordinate (0,5) for example, then one second later
a new value is taken from the queue and is added to 0 on the x-axis.
the coordinate (0,5) now has to move to the right so it becomes (1,5).

every second a y-value is taken from the queue so the linechart should move every second.

What is the best way to do this with the ChartEngine framework?
I tried to repaint the chart and all it's values every second but i guess there's be a better and more performance friendly way to do this

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private GraphicalView mChart;

private XYSeries visitsSeries ;
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;

private XYSeriesRenderer visitsRenderer;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    // Setting up chart
    setupChart();

    // Start plotting chart
    new ChartTask().execute();

}

private void setupChart(){

    // Creating an  XYSeries for Visits
    visitsSeries = new XYSeries("Unique Visitors");


    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    // Adding Visits Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(visitsSeries);        


    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries
    visitsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    visitsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    visitsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    visitsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    visitsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Visits Chart");
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Seconds");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Count");
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(10);

    multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(10);

    multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(2);

    // Adding visitsRenderer to multipleRenderer
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
    // should be same
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(visitsRenderer);

    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);


    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer);


    // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
    chartContainer.addView(mChart);

}


private class ChartTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{

    // Generates dummy data in a non-ui thread


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        int i = 0;
        try{
            do{
                String [] values = new String[2];
                Random r = new Random();
                int visits = r.nextInt(10);
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(visits));

                values[0] = Integer.toString(i); // x-as denkek
                values[1] = Integer.toString(visits); //bijhorende waarde y-as


                publishProgress(values);                    
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                i++;    
            }while(i<=10);
        }catch(Exception e){ }
        return null;
    }

    // Plotting generated data in the graph
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
    {
        visitsSeries.add(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]));
        mChart.repaint();
    }

}    

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}